# Fit image of random size into a UIWebview (IOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

[image]

I want to fit large image into UIwebview with keeping image ratio same as image view.

How can i do it.?

My code as follows to fit image in Uiwebview.
if image is large then display is not good.

```
                CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
                CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;

                NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='user-scalable=yes,width=device-width'></head><body bgcolor='000000'><img src='%@' width='%f' height='%f' style='max-width:200% max-height:200%'></body></html>"];
                imageHTML  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:htmlString, fileUrl, screenWidth, screenHeight];

        [Webview loadHTMLString:imageHTML baseURL:nil];
        [imageHTML release];
```

Comment: Why are you using a web view to show an image? Why not use a `UIImageView`?

Comment: when i used UIImageView memory is using more.Runtime memory issue is coming with iPod4 device.

Comment: if image is big (2000 * 3000) then only i am using UIwebview. otherwise i am using UIImageView.

Comment: Can you not resize the image before displaying it? There's not much value on trying to display such a big image on an iPhone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**I have used below code and its working well.**

```
   NSString *imageHTML = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"<!DOCTYPE html>"
                                 "<html lang=\"ja\">"
                                 "<head>"
                                 "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
                                 "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                                 "html{margin:0;padding:0;}"
                                 "body {"
                                 "margin: 0;"
                                 "padding: 0;"
                                 "color: #363636;"
                                 "font-size: 90%;"
                                 "line-height: 1.6;"
                                 "background: black;"
                                 "}"
                                 "img{"
                                 "position: absolute;"
                                 "top: 0;"
                                 "bottom: 0;"
                                 "left: 0;"
                                 "right: 0;"
                                 "margin: auto;"
                                 "max-width: 100%;"
                                 "max-height: 100%;"
                                 "}"
                                 "</style>"
                                 "</head>"
                                 "<body id=\"page\">"
                                 "<img src='",fileUrl,@"'/> </body></html>"];

                [wview_contents loadHTMLString:imageHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: how this will be written in swift?

Comment: I have found I just needed to add the img {max-width: 100%} to the style to make this work

Comment: works perfect. I think this is only valid solution I have come across so far . I have tried a lot of them to fit the image in the web view , but each one has its issues or drawbacks.

Answer (score 5):

To load image in Swift 3.0 from application document directory in a UIWebView with his expected ratio -

```html
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
            
            
            
        let fullHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
            "<html lang=\"ja\">" +
            "<head>" +
            "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">" +
            "<style type=\"text/css\">" +
            "html{margin:0;padding:0;}" +
            "body {" +
            "margin: 0;" +
            "padding: 0;" +
            "color: #363636;" +
            "font-size: 90%;" +
            "line-height: 1.6;" +
            "background: black;" +
            "}" +
            "img{" +
            "position: absolute;" +
            "top: 0;" +
            "bottom: 0;" +
            "left: 0;" +
            "right: 0;" +
            "margin: auto;" +
            "max-width: 100%;" +
            "max-height: 100%;" +
            "}" +
            "</style>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body id=\"page\">" +
            "<img src='\(path)'/> </body></html>"
            
            imgWbView.loadHTMLString(fullHTML, baseURL: nil)
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Set your WebView page to scale fit:

```
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

**EDIT:**

Here check these two lines also

```
CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
```

If you know what size you want them pass static values here, will fix your problem.

e.g.

```
CGFloat screenWidth = 300;
CGFloat screenHeight = 300;
```

Comment: I used it but not worked.



        wview_contents.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        wview_contents.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

Comment: Can you please post a ScreenShot for that

Comment: I did test for image resolution 2448x3264. Check it by passing static values in screenWidth and screenHeight.

Comment: if i set the value based on the orientation then may be work.

Comment: @Kampai Could you please help me to solve my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151187/uiwebview-zooming-pdf-and-large-images-zoom-by-defaults-ios

Answer (score 3):

The following code snippet may help you

```
NSString *fontString = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html>\
    <head>\
    <style>\
    img{";
        NSString *imageDimensionsStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"max-width: %fpx; max-height: %fpx;}",self.view.frame.size.width - 50.0f, self.view.frame.size.height/2];
        fontString =[fontString stringByAppendingString:imageDimensionsStr];
fontString = [fontString stringByAppendingString:@"</style></head><body>"];
    fontString = [[fontString stringByAppendingString:htmlString] stringByAppendingString:@"</body></html>"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:fontString baseURL:nil];
```

The above code will resize the width and height of the image according to view dimension. You can change according to your requirement.

Comment: This is the best solution for me, as I need to display some HTML text from a RESTful API.  In fact, I use "max-width: 100%" instead of "max-width: ... max-height".  using percentage works so well that even rotating to landscape work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me to fit the image size within width of device for Swift 5 
Helpful with dynamic html from server

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
   
    let fontAdjust = "var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"

    let imgAdjust = "var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'img { display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"
webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(imgAdjust)

    webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(fontAdjust)
    webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(imgAdjust)
}
```

Comment: identical answer as in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit/65965373#65965373