# WKWebView equivalent for UIWebView's scalesPageToFit

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I am updating my iOS app to replace `UIWebView` with `WKWebView`. However I don't understand how to achieve the same behavior with `WKWebView`. With `UIWebView` I used `scalesPageToFit` to ensure the web pag was displayed with the same size as the screen size (so as to appear full screen without scrolling).

I found that solution on the web however it does not work :

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSString *javascript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascript completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Comment: try this:  `NSString* js = 
  @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); "
   "meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); "
   "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width' ); "
   "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";

  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];`
replace your code with above code.

Comment: I gave it a try but I have the same result (by the way, the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method does not exist in WKWebView so I kept my evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler call

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 142):

you can also try the WKUserScript.

here's my working config:

```
NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;

wkWebV = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:wkWebConfig];
```

you can add additional configuration to your WKWebViewConfiguration.

Comment: Works great for me - only minor tweak was changing WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd to WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart

Comment: If I change `WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd` to `WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart` then it doesn't work for me. It doesn't add this script. any reason?

Comment: you should check for other scripts that might be overwriting your custom script.

Comment: Nice answer, but I would also add this script to avoid webkit changing the font sizes by itself: `var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);`

Comment: @MahmoudAdam what do you mean it does not work with iOS9? I'm actually still using that in swift config. And not, that config will only work for iOS8 and later, iOS7 and below doesn't have webkit framework.

Comment: @nferocious76 when I set `device-height` & `device-width` it does not work with iOS9 but when I sent them to exact numbers it works, Also do you have any idea to support different orientations?

Comment: @MahmoudAdam you should consider the injection time and 'nitWithFrame:' of your wkwebview

Comment: This worked out great.  I was trying to align a special title with Auto Layout using WKWebView.  The height of the element from offsetHeight kept coming back too big until I added this script.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've faced some issues on iPad iOS8.

Comment: Looks like we need to change `device-width` to `=device-height` when in landscape on iOS.

Comment: @TimurBernikowich no.. just add support for handling orientation changed. and those two values should interchange.. on that note what issues did you encountered?

Comment: @nferocious76 can you provide sample? I've tried opening my VC with web view in landspace without any rotations and it still appears incorrect. (width is limited to "device-portrait-width")

Comment: @nferocious76 This solutions works perfectly when only text content is on my loadRequest URL. But when image and text both are on the URL at that time image looks proper but text size looks smaller.

Comment: @VivekShah you probably need to add a config for your font sizes.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @nferocious76.

Comment: Working nice. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

Echo of nferocious76's answer, in swift code:
Swift2.x version

```
let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jscript, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
let wkUController = WKUserContentController()
wkUController.addUserScript(userScript)
let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController
let youWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: wkWebConfig)
```

swift3 version

```
let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jscript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
let wkUController = WKUserContentController()
wkUController.addUserScript(userScript)
let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController
let yourWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: wkWebConfig)
```

Answer (score 27):

Similar to @nferocious76's but in Swift language

```
var scriptContent = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');"
scriptContent += "meta.name='viewport';"
scriptContent += "meta.content='width=device-width';"
scriptContent += "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"

webView.evaluateJavaScript(scriptContent, completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! this also solved my problem to make html font size become bigger, didn't refresh from small to big. I'm using this to "refresh" the content font size and inner layout.

Answer (score 20):

I figured out below soultion. For making the content to fit with the device size.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {     for making the content to fit with the device size
    let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jscript)
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, Thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

C# version, for use in Xamarin Custom Renderer:

```
string jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

WKUserScript wkUScript = new WKUserScript((NSString)jScript, WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
WKUserContentController wkUController = new WKUserContentController();
wkUController.AddUserScript(wkUScript);

WKWebViewConfiguration wkWebConfig = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
wkWebConfig.UserContentController = wkUController;
WKWebView webView=new WKWebView(Frame, wkWebConfig);
```

Comment: Work like charm!

Comment: How does the custom renderer looks like? Do you inheriting from `WkWebViewRenderer`? Because `Control` as well as `SetNativeControl()` are unknown ...

Comment: Ok it seems that you need to inherit from `ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>` and use `OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)`.

Comment: Thank you for this it certainly helped resolve my Xamarin.Forms issue where HTML was being cut off even though I was resizing the height based on the content in `DidFinishNavigation`

Answer (score 13):

Adding the below to my HTML script helped me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=YES">
```

It does the same as scalePageToFit in UIWebView.

refer: [How to set iOS WkWebview zoom scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558441/how-to-set-ios-wkwebview-zoom-scale/58664524#58664524?newreg=0dee8591d0ae4e0ea5529aa279f1f358)

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 solution:

```
let javaScript = """
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
                meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
                meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width');
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    """

webView.evaluateJavaScript(javaScript)
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me, I added two attributes in meta: `initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=yes`, that help fit text with html have a big image in html.

```
let jscript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=yes'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
        
let userScript = WKUserScript(source: jscript, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)

let wkUController = WKUserContentController()
        
wkUController.addUserScript(userScript)
        
let wkWebConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        
wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController

self.webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: wkWebConfig)
```

Answer (score 1):

None of this answers were working for me. I was trying to open an Amazon URL for a particular artist. Turns out that Amazon has a mobile responsive URL and a desktop URL. On desktop Safari, I changed to iPhone as user-agent (Develop > User Agent > Safari - iOS 13.1.3 - iPhone) and got the appropriate URL for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to fit the image size within width of device for Swift 5 
Helpful with dynamic html from server

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
   
    let fontAdjust = "var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"

    let imgAdjust = "var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'img { display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"
webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(imgAdjust)

    webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(fontAdjust)
    webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(imgAdjust)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Swift code to use in an extension

```
extension WKWebView {

func addInitialScaleMetaTag() {
    evaluateJavaScript(
    """
        var meta = document.createElement("meta");
        meta.name = "viewport";
        meta.content = "initial-scale=1.0";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    """) { result, error in
        // handle error
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

// 100% work for me

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    //print(#function)
    let scriptFontSizeAdjustment = "var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"

    let scriptImgSizeAdjustment = "var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML = 'img { display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%; }';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"

    webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(scriptFontSizeAdjustment)
    webKitView.evaluateJavaScript(scriptImgSizeAdjustment)

}
```