# swift WKwebview is no scalesPageToFit Property？

Tags: swift, wkwebview

WKWebView no `scalesPageToFit` Property？

I use `UIWebView` can set `scalesPageToFit=true`

I want to embed WebPage requires this property

Comment: Its in Obj-C but this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit

Comment: you can see the answer at [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `UIWebView`, `WKWebView` doesn't have a `scalesPageToFit` property (in either language). Instead zoom is handled by the underlying `UIScrollView`.