# Webview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to integrate webpage into an Ios application.
I have created a webpage using D3 js and SVG elements.
I am trying to display the webpage on Ipad Pro 12.9" 2nd generation.
But somehow it is showing only a 1/4 portion of my webpage in webView.

Here is the webpage URL -
http://ec2-54-198-148-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/webapp/question

I got iPad pro-resolution from apple website which is 1366X1024 so I have created a webpage for the same resolution.

I have verified webpage on browsers like safari, chrome, firefox and it's looking perfect on it with 1366X1024 resolution.

Attached screenshot BrowserScreenCap taken with 1366 X 1024 on browser and IpadAppScreenCap took on iPad application.
I am using WKwebView on IOS side. I have verified webpage layout on simulator only.
How we make that webpage fullscreen?

[image: BrowserScreenCap]
[image: iPadAppScreenCap]

Comment: What about constraints of your WKwebView? Have you set them properly?

Comment: how you configured the constraints of your WebView?

Comment: check fit content property

Comment: Check if this can help you . [WKWebView equivalent for UIWebView's scalesPageToFit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit)

Answer (score 0):

Content from the link mentioned in comment.

```
NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

    WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
    WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    [wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

    WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let url: URL = URL(string: "http://ec2-54-198-148-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/webapp/question")!
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add the below tag into your html body

```
<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no\">
```

if you want you can enable user-scable=yes for zooming