# WKWebView: scalesPageToFit behaviour without Java Script

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How to get `scalesPageToFit` behaviour for HTML content displayed in a `WKWebView` *without using JavaScript*? (disabling JS is a requirement for in our case).

Sorry for not posting any code, but I have no idea how I could achieve this. All solutions I know and all I found are based on JS. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26583062/1457385).

I already add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>` to the HTML if it does not exist yet, but at least images are often displayed way too big.

All images are provided to `WKWebView` by a `WKURLSchemeHandler`.

Answer (score 7):

Please put

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

inside your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
    mutating func fitContentToScreen() {
        self.add(prefix: "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, user-scalable=yes'></header>")
    }
}
```

You add this header line to html content to fit screen.