# Equivalent WKWebView for UIWebView's scalesPageToFit BUT set to FALSE

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit) add an instance of `WKUserScript` to set `scalesPageToFit` value to `true`, but I need to create two methods that enable and disable `scalesPageToFit`.

Enabling is already answered in that post but I need to know how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the framework I managed to call a method for `WKUserContentController` to remove all associated user scripts. A `WKUserContentController` object provides a way for JavaScript to post messages to a web view ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller))

```
- (void) disableZoom {
    [self.webview.configuration.userContentController removeAllUserScripts];
}
```