# WebView in ios open as desktop mode Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use WebView to open a site, site is using responsive design.

On Android the site fills the page and work correctly [Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHLsG.jpg)

My Problem in IOS it appears as it open in desktop not in mobile mode [IOS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVOvg.png)

I am a new in flutter but i solved this problem in Xamarin
[This the same Problem in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437800/webview-in-ios-open-as-desktop-mode/63445660?noredirect=1#comment112253201_63445660)

This is code Used to Open Web View by dart language in flutter

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(_title),
      backgroundColor: dark_blue,
    ),
    body: WebView(
      initialUrl: _selectedUrl,
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
      },
      navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
        if (request.url.contains('https://helper')) {
          CompletePaymentFun();
          return NavigationDecision.prevent;
        }
        return NavigationDecision.navigate;
      },
    ));}
```

this is my solution in c# I made a custom Webview in ios but I don't know how to solve it in flutter using dart language.

```
class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";
    WKUserContentController userController;

    public CustomWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration())
    {
    }

    public CustomWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {

        userController = config.UserContentController;
        var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
        userController.AddUserScript(script);
        config.UserContentController = userController;
        WKWebView webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
    }

}
```

Comment: try with this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview

Answer (score 3):

I solved same problem with this code.

```
WebView(
    key: _key,
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    initialUrl: "${routeArguments.url}",
    gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      this.controller = controller;
    },
    onPageFinished: (url){
      controller.evaluateJavascript(
            "function toMobile(){"
            "var meta = document.createElement('meta'); "
            "meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');"
            " meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'); "
            "var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];"
            "head.appendChild(meta); "
            "}"
            "toMobile()"
      );
    },
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

**pubspec.yaml**

```
flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class WebViewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final url;

  WebViewContainer(this.url);

  @override
  createState() => _WebViewContainerState(this.url);
}

class _WebViewContainerState extends State<WebViewContainer> {
  var _url="https://www.amazon.in/?&_encoding=UTF8&tag=bappasaikh-21&linkCode=ur2&linkId=e3b009b026920c3cfdd6185fadfb7e67&camp=3638&creative=24630";
  final _key = UniqueKey();

  _WebViewContainerState(this._url);


//to load desktop mode
  String js = "document.querySelector('meta[name=\"viewport\"]').setAttribute('content', 'width=1024px, initial-scale=' + (document.documentElement.clientWidth / 1024))";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final flutterWebViewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen((event) {
      debugPrint("Progress $event");

      //this will make show in desktop mode
      flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript(js);

    });



    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Desktop Mode"),
      ),
      url: _url,
      withJavascript: true,
      useWideViewPort: true,
      displayZoomControls: false,
      scrollBar: true,
      withZoom: true,
      userAgent: js,
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package.

I was able to force the InAppWebView to use the mobile version of my website by setting the [preferredContentMode](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/webview-options/) field of the InAppWebViewOptions object to UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE:

```
InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.MOBILE, // ADD THIS
    ),
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true,
      hardwareAcceleration: true,
    ),
    ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true, 
    ),
  );
```

Then you can plug the options into the InAppWebView widget like so:

```
InAppWebView(
    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(model.url)),
    initialOptions: options,
....

);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36";
class Web1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Web1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Web1> createState() => _Web1State();
}
class _Web1State extends State<Web1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: url,
        userAgent: userAgent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```