# Fit HTML content to web view

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I tried to fit the HTML content into my web view and for that, I tried to add a different kind of script into it and by using constraint, I changed its height as well. Now, the problem is that the width of the content not fits into `WkWebView` content and exceeds it. I checked another application where it just fits into the content but not in my case.

*Here are the scripts and code I already to tried to resolve the issue:*

1. Using `meta data` into the header and append it to HTML string

   ```
   var headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0'></header>"
   headerString.append(data)
   webView.loadHTMLString(data, baseURL: nil)
   ```
2. Inject `JS` into `WKWebView` using `WKUserScript`

   ```
   private func getZoomDisableScript() -> WKUserScript {
       let source = """
       var meta = document.createElement('meta');
                   meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
                   meta.setAttribute('content', 'width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0);
                   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
       """

       return WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
   }

   webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(getZoomDisableScript())
   ```

And here is the code to evaluate `JS`

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { [self] (complete, error) in
        if complete != nil {
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily =\"-apple-system\"")
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { [self] (height, error) in
                if !isHeightRendered {
                    delegate?.renderedHeight(height as! CGFloat)
                    isHeightRendered = true
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Also tried different ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295277/wkwebview-equivalent-for-uiwebviews-scalespagetofit) but none works for me. Here is the screenshot of the other app that fits contents into `WebView` and for them, it works.

[image]

The result I get

[image]

So, Is there anything I am doing wrong or Is there anything to add to fits into the web view content?