# How do I set textalignment property to right in uiwebview in IOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, text-alignment

I am rendering data from the service in the uiwebview, but i need to show the content in the webview from right to left, how to do that i have tried the following thing, but it doesnot apply to the content.

Here is my code.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<div align='right'>%@<div>",configdata] baseURL:nil];
```

If any code changes is there please help me. thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out this answer, may be help a bit- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252101/fit-image-of-random-size-into-a-uiwebview-ios/26252838#26252838

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dot the solution for my answer, this is the code.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div dir='rtl'>%@<div>",configdata] baseURL:nil];
```

Here use dir = 'rtl', it resolved my question.

Comment: "rtl" is not a text alignment; it's a text direction. Your question was misleading.

Comment: Its not misleading, i just got an different solution for my question, i was intimating that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to style your div. By applying the `text-align` attribute. Give it a try. Just as advice, if you have a bunch of such `div` elements I recommend you to not use inline-style.

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:right'>%@<div>",configdata] baseURL:nil];
```