# Image doesn't fit web view

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, nsurl

Am displaying a Image on a web view and it doesn't fit the web view completely and shows blank white space around the border.How can i fit or scale the image completely to the size of [image]web view?

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        self.webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        self.webView.delegate = self;
        [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: Have a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252101/fit-image-of-random-size-into-a-uiwebview-ios/26252838#26252838

Answer (score 1):

Try this html code snippet

```
<html><body><img src='%@' width='100%' height='100%'></body></html>
```

It will fill the web view completely without any white space.

Answer (score 0):

try to load like this

```
 - (void) showImageWithLoadHTMLString {
        // Create URL string for image file location

        NSURL    *imageURL   = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];

        // Create HTML string from image URL

        NSString *htmlString = @"<html><body><img src='%@' width='900'></body></html>";
        NSString *imageHTML  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:htmlString, imageURL];

        // Load image in UIWebView
        self.webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:imageHTML baseURL:nil];
    }
```

Comment: change width='900' and try

Comment: still you are getting same @puneethakoopadira

Comment: I used this and image got scaled too much which i don't need. NSString *htmlString = @"<html><body><img src='%@' width='900'></body></html>";
        NSString *imageHTML  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:htmlString, imageURL];

Comment: can I retain my old code with some other color instead of white empty space below image

Comment: NSString *htmlString = @"<html><body><img src='%@' width='700'></body></html>"; NSString *imageHTML = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:htmlString, imageURL];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65739/discussion-between-sport-and-puneetha-koopadira).

Comment: how to change white empty space color to some other color?

Comment: self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];